# Check matching text in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Check the jquery code bellow. I want to itarate though list of text from array `successMessage` and find if there any match in `pageHtml` variable. If u check there already a matching world `message` but `console.log(match)` always returning null. Whats wrong i am doing here? [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ayuLox7s/2/)

```
    const successMessage = [
      "お名前",
      "another success message"
    ];
  
  jQuery.each(successMessage, function(index, success_msg) {
    //console.log(success_msg);
    var pageHtml = "message";
    var match = pageHtml.match('/'+success_msg+'/gi');
    console.log(match);
  });
```

Comment: You are just building a string, you do not have a regular expression. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp is how you make a reg exp from a string

Comment: anyone can implement with my example? this would easy to understand for me

Comment: i tried like this but not works- `var match = pageHtml.match('/'+'#'+success_msg+'#'+'/gi');`

Comment: Did you not look at the duplicate? The selected answer in the duplicate shows you what to do. It uses replace, you want to use match